# Installing Battlefield 3 from a Bluray disc without the game box

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3

I found a bluray disc of Battlefield 3 without the box. Will I be able to install it on a PS3 without a box/key or do I need a serial key that might have been on a box?

Comment: While I don't believe you need a key to install BF3, the game can be purchased for as little as 99 cents at Gamestop (US). It is very easy to find a cheap copy of the game with a code if it required one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at my box and there is no serial key on this game you should be fine to install it.  There were several games with online codes in this era but this does not appear to be one.  At most you might miss out on a promotional item that is no longer valid due to those having expiration dates on them.